# import css from node modules react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, css-loader, react-boilerplate

I am trying to import a css file from node_modules.

My webpack config:

```
  {
    // Preprocess 3rd party .css files located in node_modules
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

Furthermore, I woud like to import it in custom header component, like this:

```
import 'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-default.css';
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Does anybody know what the problem is here?